# Destructure array in conditional

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have an api that returns a single boolean value inside an array.
How can I destructure the variable inside a conditional?

```
let condition = [true];


if (...condition) {
    // do stuff
}
```

I'm aware I could use `condition[0]` but a destructure-ish solution seems more reasonable since if the array contained multiple values, each of them could be evaluated (`let condition = [true, true, true]`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
> [true, true].every(x => x)
true
> [true, false].every(x => x)
false
```

So:

```
let condition = [true, true, true];
if (condition.every(x => x)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I think it's worth noting that `condition.every` always returns true if `condition` is an empty array. So, if `condition` is empty, then `[].every(x => x)`, `[].every(x => !x)`, `[].every(x => undefined)` all return true. If something goes wrong and the consumer of the api gets an empty array, then this solution would likely cause the application to do the wrong thing, and it is usually better to throw an error than to do the wrong thing.

Comment: @Aweston Regarding the behavior, I agree. But a usual for-loop solution like `let r = true; for (const x of condition) if (!x) r = false` would also produce `true` for an empty array. And I don't think this is likely undesirable: e.g., if `condition` contains constraints to meet (as the name of the variable suggests), then passing `[]` should produce `true` (as no constraints are unmet). The external logic and the corresponding validation are just out of scope of this question. But thanks for noticing this corner case!

Comment: I mean yeah, but OP specifically said they were expecting exactly one boolean value, and it sounds to me that they were thinking of using destructuring because it's generalizable to other cases where they get boolean arrays if other lengths.

Answer (score 4):

Just take an array with the variable.

```
let [condition] = [true];
```

For multiple vlaues, you could take more variables, like

```
let [cond1, cond2, cond3] = [true, false, true];
```

Comment: Looks nice, but what if there are 1000 values?

Comment: @KoshVery, if you like to get some value of a special index, you could take `let { 42: cond42, 57: cond57 } = someArray;` for destructuring values at a ginven index. for all values in an array, the array would be the better data structure.

Comment: both answers look really amazing and I upvoted both. I'll accept @Kirill Bulygin 's however since that one works for infinite values inside the condition array

Comment: @NinaScholz, I know how destructuring works, thank you. I asked something different. Would your solution look the same `let [cond1, cond2, .. cond1000]` if there were 1000 values?

Comment: @KoshVery, well, the question is quite unclear what should happen with more than one element. i actually do not know, what you want to highlight.

Comment: @NinaScholz if you have time can you look at this:         https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/200376/adding-the-repetitions-and-expanding-recursively